# How can I use my iPad as a graphics tablet?

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation

I have an iPad and would like to use it as a [graphics tablet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OOWC3I) for recording video tutorials on my computer.

What software should I use to allow the iPad to be an input device to control my PC directly? I want to be able to draw on my computer via the iPad. It would work like the Bamboo Pen Tablet like the one in the "graphics tablet" link.

Comment: What does a graphics tablet have to do with videos?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the iPad to control the mouse cursor on your computer?

Comment: use it instead of buying a pen tablet device and connect it to pc..then use some software on the pc to edit images, record video tutorials while i write something on the tablet

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the OS you will be running on your PC? Windows / Mac / other?

Comment: @bmike: no restrictions

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/a/1560405/62123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iPad doesn't offer the same capabilities as a Wacom graphics tablet. At best--Eazel excepted--you'll only be able to control the cursor on the mac or pc. There are many of those types of programs for the iPad in iTunes from the free touch mouse (iPhone only) to iTeleport (iPad, US$25).

Graphics tablets aren't that expensive, especially compared to an iPad. The cheapest Wacom tablet in the USA goes for $200 or so. Ask someone you know to give you one for your birthday or appropriate holiday. If you know enough people, you might even be able to find one for free. I gave away my old Wacom Graphire last year when I bought a new Intuos. Ebay shows used Graphires for a variety of prices; make sure used tablets include the pen and mouse.

I also have made video tutorials using a graphics tablet and Photoshop. I have not settled on which video capture software to use. There are too many for me recommend one.

Comment: It's amazing that it took four years for the iPad to surpass graphics tablets, but for some the Air2 is as good as entry Wacom, and the iPad Pro seems superior to any other tablet shipping.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is Avatron's AirPad software. http://avatron.com/apps/air-display I've just downloaded the Windows version and so far it seems stable enough, though I'm sure the Mac version is even more solid, since the Windows version appears to be relatively new.

That having been said, it's pretty impressive and does exactly what you want to do EXCEPT of course, there's no touch sensitivity, and there will always be a bit of lag (heck, Graphic tablets have lag too, believe it, but just a lot less).

Check it out!

Comment: "Air Stylus" is the input app, but it does not currently have Windows support.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Photoshop CS5, check out [Eazel](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-eazel-for-photoshop/id421302663?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

Extra late post, but it might be useful for anyone searching this subsequently.
[Astropad](https://www.macworld.com/article/3237307/astropad-studio-review.html) is the app you need if you are using a Mac desktop, it is excellent.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: User has a PC, not a Mac, and needs an app to enable input from the iPad into a Windows PC.